# 1064 SQL Syntax error on `wp_commentmeta`

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error on PhPMyAdmin when uploading a database - Have I deleted a key line of code?

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.8.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: custsql-ipg100.eigbox.net
-- Generation Time: Mar 16, 2015 at 05:46 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.40
-- PHP Version: 4.4.9
-- 
-- Database: `wrd_2macd1bm7n`
-- 
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
-- 
   CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

     `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
     `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
     `meta_value` LONGTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
    KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
    KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` )
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Here is the error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
>         `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL A' at line 1

Comment: Show the actual error message instead of making us guess

Comment: @JohnConde hope that's what you need?

Comment: Yep. That's what we're looking for.

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using for the import?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause of this error is a missing semicolon on the previous statement. That is, MySQL is balking at the occurrence of `CREATE TABLE` because it's seeing that as a continuation of (part of) a preceding statement which wasn't terminated.

Comment: The SQL text given in the question seems to execute just fine; doesn't appear to be any syntax issue with the SQL statement shown. (What we're not shown is the lines immediately preceding this statement.)

Comment: Thanks I just added the lines preceding the statement but before that is my database name.

Comment: I tried adding a semicolon after the 'wp_commentmeta' but it still doesn't work